# Django: transfering two primary keys to new detail view

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to create a detail view where I use **employee** and **subject name** to show the **evaluations** created in the specific subject.

I currently have this detail where, where I'm looping through the subject names and displaying all the evaluations for the subject for the employee. The view is using employee as the primary key.

So when I press on the subject name from the loop below, I wish to go to a new view where I show the evaluations for the subject by the specific employee.

**Employee template**

```
{% for subject in subject_list %}
      <a href="{% url 'evalsys:fag_evaluering_detail' employee.pk subject.pk %}"><h5>{{ subject.subjectname }}</h5></a>
    {% for evaluation in subject.evaluation_set.all %}
        {{ evaluation.instructor }}
        {{ evaluation.ma }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I can't figure out what the best way to do this is. I believe using the employee primary key for the new view is correct, but how do I "transfer" the subject id from the loop to the next view?

Alternatively I can use the subject id for the view but then I don't understand how to "transfer" the employee over.

**Employee view with subjects**

```
class EmployeeEvalDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'evalsys/evalueringer/se_alle_evalueringer.html'
    model = Employee

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeEvalDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['fagene'] = Subject.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('evaluation_set', queryset=Evaluation.objects.filter(ma=self.object)))
        return context
```

**Employee model**

```
class Medarbejder(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    ma = models.IntegerField(help_text="Indtast medarbejderens MA-nummer. (F.eks 123456)")
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens fornavn.")
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens efternavn.")
    subject = models.ManyToManyField('Subject', related_name='medarbejder', through='Evaluering')
```

**Evaluering model**

```
class Evaluering(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    oprettet = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    opdateret = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    ma = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    subjectname = models.ForeignKey('Subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)              
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**Subject model**

```
 class Subject(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        subjectname = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Indtast navnet på faget.")
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

**New detail view with multiple PK's**

```
class FagEvalDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'evalsys/evalueringer/eksporter/detail_fag_eval.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FagEvalDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        context['pk_alt'] = Subject.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk_alt', ''))
        return context
```

Comment: Same as anything else, you define a URL that accepts the IDs and use them in the destination view.

Comment: Both the Employee PK and the Subject PK then, right? Couldn't find much about multiple pk's in URL.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were expecting to find. What's specific about putting multiple PKs in a URL?

Comment: I get this error when trying to use multiple PK's in the URL.
ValueError at /evaluering/employee/2/1/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
`path('evaluering/employee/<int:pk>/<int:alt_pk>/', views.FagEvalDetailView.as_view(), name='fag_evaluering_detail'),`

Comment: Updated the post, at the bottom is my view im using to use two pk's in url.

Comment: That error is saying you didn't actually provide the alt_pk value in the URL.

Comment: Hmm I don’t really understand why that is, maybe to do with the template? Must I have subject.alt_pk and not subject.pk?

Comment: I'm confused. Which template are you talking about here? In any case, show the actual link you are going to and how you generate that link in the template.

Comment: I updated the post under**employee template**. Each subject has a anchor tag so its a link this this and I've then put this url in it:
`{% url 'evalsys:fag_evaluering_detail' employee.pk subject.pk %}`
This takes me to the url that I posted in the earlier comments, but i still get that error i mentioned.

Comment: Ok I accidently wrote alt_pk and not pk_alt. The keys work now. Still not sure how to iterate the evaluations for the subject in the new template though, keep getting told "object is not iterable".

Comment: What are you expecting to iterate? A pk by definition identifies a single item.

Comment: Right, I have this context `context['pk_alt'] = Subject.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk_alt', ''))` now I wish to use the subject pk to get all the evaluations with that pk and under the specific employee. So a context that filters the evaluations with the employee pk and the subject pk.